# Undefined Variable on mysqli_query

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli, twitter

I have similar code that works with no errors but when I try and query my database I'm getting the several errors. Can anyone help ?

errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\wamp64\www\twitter clone\functions.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\twitter clone\functions.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp64\www\twitter clone\functions.php on line 24

Code;

```
<?php

session_start();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "pass", "twitter");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['function']) == "logout"){
    session_unset();
}

function displayTweets($type) {
    if ($type == 'public'){
        $whereClause = "";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets ".$whereClause." ORDER BY 'datetime' DESC LIMIT 10";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No Tweets";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: All the errors are related to the first [**Variable scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem.

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Of course! I need to make $link global

Comment: Nooooo! I mean, yeah, that would work, but you're better off passing it as a function argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `$link` variable is not in the function's local scope.

A way to fix this is by defining the variable in the function's local scope by adding the following line to the function:

```
global $link
```

Please have a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to read more about the variable scope in PHP.

---

Edit:

An even better way would be to inject your connection by adding it as an argument to your function, which would have your code look something like this:

```
function displayTweets($type, $connection) {
    if ($type == 'public'){
        $whereClause = "";
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tweets ".$whereClause." ORDER BY 'datetime' DESC LIMIT 10";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo "No Tweets";
    }
}
```

After this, you would call your function using `displayTweets('public',$link)`, with 'public' being the type, and `$link` being your defined connection

---

Also, in your current function, `$whereClause` could be undefined. I'm guessing your aware of this, just wanted to state it in case you get errors on that.

Comment: Maybe it's better to inject the connection as a function argument.

Comment: It definitely would be. Forgot that as I started typing, edited the answer

Comment: When injecting the connection as in the edited answer, don't forget to add it in the argument list in the function call: `displayTweets(something, $link);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $link variable as global variable ($GLOBALS['link']) in displayTweets function or you have to pass $link as parameter.

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $query);

or

displayTweets('public',$link);